# How do I remove hacked money?

Tags: payday-2

I recently played PAYDAY 2 with a hacker. He did not use hacks through the main session but at the end I seemed to get 1 billion dollars into my spending cash. I am sure this was a hacker as it said that I made it out with 1389 bags in the summary.

Anyway, I want to know if there is a way I can remove the hacked money from my account as I don't want to cheat at this game. I don't want to download any special hacking kits or anything I just want to remove 1 billion dollars from my spending cash. Can I do that?

Comment: Nice guy, doesn't want to steal money in a game about stealing money.

Comment: I just want to get my level and money legit.

Comment: There is no way to remove it and you will probably get a cheater flag soon.

Comment: @odixon Has nothing to do with VAC. It is a system running alongside VAC that detects esp. xp and money cheaters.

Comment: There is no VAC in Payday 2.

Comment: To add to 0-frame link's comment here, the anti-cheat in Payday 2 is primarily focused on preventing people from using DLC weapons or items without actually owning the DLC (and even then, there's been false positives). There's a few other things that can trigger it, but the amount of money or your XP will NEVER trigger Overkill's anti-cheat. Hoxhud also has some (annoyingly buggy and on-by-default) anti-cheat measures, and those similarly don't check against a client's XP and Money because that information currently doesn't get sent to the host.

Comment: I am glad that I will not get flagged by Overkill thankyou everyone who has helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, there is a way, and it is Overkill approved.

If you have HoxHud, which is a HUD that is Overkill approved, it automatically has a feature that will detect if a payout bonus is too high.  If it does detect it,  it will prompt you after a game ends, saying:

> Uh-Oh, Cheated Mission Alert!
>
> Looks like you were in a mission with a cheater, would you like to
>   reset your spending to $xxx, and your offshore to $xxx?  Yes/No

And you will have the option to automatically remove "hacked" money. Here's an example below:

[image]

Comment: Hoxhud only does it after the specific mission - if you already had "hacked money", Hoxhud will not touch it. In addition, Olipro's been getting a lot of heat over his blatant refusal to do anything to make Hoxhud compatible with BLT, to the point of forking the BLT and having the old LUA injector run alongside it (which defeats the entire point behind the BLT) all so that he doesn't have to do anything to HoxHud.

Comment: Thankyou this is a good answer however unfortunately I had to remove HoxHud because my game crashed too much.

Comment: FYI HoxHud is now considered dead (and it wasn't a very good mod to begin with, riddled with crashy malware and DRM). "Overkill-approved" only means that they pestered Overkill until they were forced to say that it wasn't a cheat. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

Buying and selling the same weapon over and over will slowly eat down the amount of spending cash. If you are below Infamy Level V, going infamous will also completely reset your spending cash to 0. (going to Infamy level VI and above will not reset your spending cash anymore) Those are the only reliable means to remove cash.

Note that just having excess cash (due to hackers or extremely good runs on White XMAS or Cook Off) will NOT trigger a cheater flag, and you're very likely to accumulate similar amounts of cash if you work your way up from Infamy V to Infamy XXV. Spending Cash also becomes stupidly easy to come by after Infamy I and one of the current methods of quickly leveling up also generates a nice amount of Spending Cash anyways.

[edit: as of PC update 100 (the skill tree overhaul), skills no longer have a money cost associated with them, so it is no longer possible to use them to remove spending cash obtained from a session that had a hacker.]

Comment: This will work thank you. I am currently infamy 9 so I can keep becoming more infamous however I will be able to keep buying and selling weapons.